# How to upload big files to s3 without running into MemoryError

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, memory-management

I am writing a code that given a pandas dataframe, uploads it as a csv to a given s3 bucket.
The thing is that with huge files I am getting a memory error.
I tried to solve this by dividing the df into chunks and uploading them separately, but I still running into the same error.

The code I am using is this:

```
import io
import boto3
import concurrent.futures

def send_df_to_s3(df, bucket_name, key_name, chunk_size=100 * 1024 * 1024, num_threads=4):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    
    # Create the multipart upload
    response = s3.create_multipart_upload(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=key_name)
    upload_id = response['UploadId']
    
    parts = []
    part_futures = {}
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=num_threads) as executor:
        for i, chunk in enumerate(chunked_dataframe(df, chunk_size)):
            # Upload the chunk
            future = executor.submit(
                s3.upload_part,
                Body=chunk,
                Bucket=bucket_name,
                Key=key_name,
                UploadId=upload_id,
                PartNumber=i+1
            )
            part_futures[future] = i + 1
            
            # Wait for some parts to finish uploading before starting new ones
            if len(part_futures) == num_threads:
                for part_future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(part_futures):
                    parts.append({'ETag': part_future.result()['ETag'], 'PartNumber': part_futures[part_future]})
                part_futures = {}
        
        # Wait for any remaining parts to finish uploading
        for part_future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(part_futures):
            parts.append({'ETag': part_future.result()['ETag'], 'PartNumber': part_futures[part_future]})
        
    parts.sort(key= lambda x: x['PartNumber'])
    # Complete the multipart upload
    response = s3.complete_multipart_upload(
        Bucket=bucket_name,
        Key=key_name,
        UploadId=upload_id,
        MultipartUpload={'Parts': parts}
    )
    
    return response

def chunked_dataframe(df, chunk_size):
    """
    Chunk a DataFrame into smaller CSV strings of maximum `chunk_size` bytes.
    """
    csv_buffer = io.StringIO()
    for i, chunk in df.groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // len(df) * chunk_size):
        yield chunk.to_csv(index=False).encode('utf-8')
```

As I said, this works with small dataframes but with large dataframes I get the MemoryError at the line:

```
yield chunk.to_csv(index=False).encode('utf-8')
```

Could you please tell me which part did I bypassed, where a lot of memory is used because of the dataframe? How can I fix it?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: You can leverage `chunksize` parameter of `read_csv` function. And upload the in memory chunked bytes directly to `s3`. I don't see why do you have to create csv files out of those chunks.

Comment: Have you tried using the AWS SDK for Pandas? https://aws-sdk-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html

Comment: I @ManashMandal, thanks for commenting.
The thing is that the df I am processing in my script is not from a csv file, but I converted some calls to ElasticSearch into a df in order to make some data analysis there.
Nowhere in the code I use the read_csv function.
I create csv files out of every file because I would like to upload the df to s3 as a csv file.

Comment: Sorry, but you can directly upload the chunked buffer to s3. You do not need to create the data frame. You are using generator that's true but at the same time you are loading the whole dataframe into memory and that is what causing the error I believe.

Comment: @ManashMandal I do need the dataframe becasue as I said said earlier I get the data from ElasticSearch and make some important transformations that can only be done with dataframes.
When I am working with the dataframe I have no problem and it stills in memory, the problem is when I try to send it to s3.